# In a Pandas Id column, how can I insert an incremented value (max + 1) for each missing Id value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, identity

In a large data set (300K rows) with an Id column (primary key), I append new rows of data. New rows do not have an Id, which I am having difficulty adding. Each new Id should be an incremented value for each row - adding 1 to the maximum value in the Id column.

The data looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# example data frame
inp = [{'Id': 0, 'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 7},
   {'Id': 1, 'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 8},
   {'Id': 2, 'Col1': 3, 'Col2': 9},
   {'Id': '', 'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 10}, 
   {'Id': 4, 'Col1': 5, 'Col2': 11},
   {'Id': '', 'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 12}
   ]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
# format to be like my real data
df["Id"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Id"], errors='coerce')
df["Id"] = df["Id"].astype("Int64")

print(df)
      Id  Col1  Col2
0     0     1     7
1     1     1     8
2     2     3     9
3  <NA>     1    10
4     4     5    11
5  <NA>     1    12
```

Needed:

```
      Id  Col1  Col2
0     0     1     7
1     1     1     8
2     2     3     9
3     5     1    10
4     4     5    11
5     6     1    12
```

Fails:

```
df["Id"] = np.select([df["Id"].isna()], [df["Id"].max() + 1], default=df["Id"])
print(df
          Id  Col1  Col2
0     0     1     7
1     1     1     8
2     2     3     9
3     5     1    10
4     4     5    11
5     5     1    12

df["Id"] = df.apply(lambda x: df["Id"].max() + 1 if ~isinstance(x["Id"], int) else x["Id"], axis=1)
   Id  Col1  Col2
0   5     1     7
1   5     1     8
2   5     3     9
3   5     1    10
4   5     5    11
5   5     1    12

df.sort_values(by=["Id"], inplace=True)
df.set_index("Id", inplace=True)
      Col1  Col2
Id              
0        1     7
1        1     8
2        3     9
4        5    11
<NA>     1    10
<NA>     1    12
```

I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track (this seems like such an obvious thing to do, but I can't find it described from the perspective I'm taking). Lambda and looping techniques were also very slow. Am I missing some simple function to do exactly this?!?

Comment: So, you want to replace `<NA>` with the corresponding value of `col2` divided by 2? Or is it just by accident that it fits to your rule?

Comment: ko3 - no, col2 is mostly irrelevant. It is just new data. I just need the max of the Id column, plus 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

- add `max()` to `cumsum` on `isna`
- `fillna` with the above

Code:

```
df['Id'] = df['Id'].fillna(df['Id'].isna().cumsum()+df['Id'].max())
```

Output:

```
   Id  Col1  Col2
0   0     1     7
1   1     1     8
2   2     3     9
3   5     1    10
4   4     5    11
5   6     1    12
```

Comment: That is truly great! IIUC, the isna and cumsum provides the incrementation, which adds to the existing max value. So good, and so fast! Danke!